# Which build tool supports a separated config folder so that no config files are in the src folder?

Tags: gradle, cmake, build, continuous-integration, scons

i am looking for a build tool that allows me to store the build tool with additional pre and postscripts as well as the build configs in folders separated from the source code.
Most build tools i tried work with config files directly in the source code folder.
Could you recommend something?

I know that it sounds like i am missusing the concept and should simply insert config files in the source code folder. Yet the reasoning behind this will blow up this post without adding a lot of value.

Comment: Both CMake and SCons, which you a listed among the tags, allow to have "config files" outside from the directory with source files. If you want to know about how exactly to do that in a concrete build tool, then ask specifically about that tool.

Comment: You can achieve this for sure with CMake, but it requires the cmake files to not write anything to the source dir, but use the binary dirs instead. I've encountered projects though that did require an update to not write to the source dirs. (I've successfully built a project in a docker container where the source repository was mounted as a readonly volume...)

Answer (score 0):

SCons can do it several different ways.
Though `Repository()` might be the simplest.

See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm46358268990080